# Add a logout link to block menu

Tags: php, drupal

I am new to Drupal and I want to add a logout link to my block menu. In my *template.php* I added this:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
     global $user;
    if ($user->uid != 0) {
      // code for the account and logout links

      $vars['block-menu-institutionnel']['account-link'] = Array (
          'attributes' => Array('title' => 'Account link'),
          'href' => '?q=user',
          'title' => t('Account')
      );
      $vars['block-menu-institutionnel']['logout-link'] = Array (
          'attributes' => Array('title' => 'Logout link'),
          'href' => 'logout',
          'title' => t('Logout')
      );
    }
    else {
      $vars['block-menu-institutionnel']['login-link'] = Array (
          'attributes' => Array('title' => 'Login link'),
          'href' => '?q=user',
          'title' => t('Login')
      );
    }

}
```

However, it won't work and I am not sure that `block-menu-institutionnel` is the true class. This what I get when I inspect the block with Firebug:

```
 <div role="navigation" class="block block-menu contextual-links-region
 no-title even block-count-2 block-region-header
 block-menu-institutionnel" id="block-menu-menu-institutionnel"><div
 class="block-inner clearfix">   <div class="block-content content"><ul
 class="menu clearfix"><li class="first leaf menu-depth-1
 menu-item-1104">...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can do it!
Go to admin > structure > menu (for Drupal 7.x)
Create a menu, then add menu items for login and register. Now go to blocks page and you will see a block with your menu name. Set it in the region you want! Easy!

Comment: i have a menu and i want to add a logout link ( will appear only if user is connected )

Comment: By menu, I meant a collection of menu item you see when you go to admin > structure > menu. Like primary menu, etc. Each time you create a 'menu', respective block is also created. You just have to add the menu items to that particular menu and use the block in the region you desire.